# My models property filtering total sum and answer correct but gave me each row what i have db

Tags: python, html, django

Below def. given me correct answer, but when i added html total sum. written me in db how many rows i have, same as row result gave?

```
def total_overtime(self):

    total = (Salary.objects
        .filter(currency='Tenge')
        .aggregate(
        total=Sum('overtime', field="overtime*overtime_hourly_rate")
    )['total'])
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
total = (Salary.objects
        .filter(currency='Tenge')
        .aggregate(
        total=Sum('overtime', field="overtime*overtime_hourly_rate")
    ).first()['total'])
```

Comment: 'dict' object has no attribute 'first' gave this problem